# Drools - Null validation failing

Tags: drools

I am trying to execute below rule in Drools through Talend

```
    rule "rule1"
    dialect "mvel"
    no-loop true
    when
        trans : row( BUS_AREA_CD == null )
    then

                trans.ACTUAL_PRODUCT_LINE_CODE="06" 

end
rule "rule2"
    dialect "mvel"
    no-loop true
    when
        trans : row( BUS_AREA_CD != null)
    then

                trans.ACTUAL_PRODUCT_LINE_CODE="96" 

end
```

Below is the data object(row) that I have created.

[image]

Below is the test scenario that I have executed

[image]

when I execute the test scenario with BUS_AREA_CD = null, it is returning blank value instead of "96".

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where is the "blank value" returned and how do you see that? How's class `row` defined? What facts did you insert? - As it is, the answer is "no".

Comment: @laune I have updated the required information.

Comment: Do you know that rule "rule1" really fired? What are the "4 rules fired in 1 ms"? Any chance that they might undo the change? -- Add a "throw" statement to the consequence of rule1, to demonstrate its firing if there's no other way. -- Use the modify statement to update WM for Drools.

Comment: rule1 did not fire at all. I have added rule 2 and add the screenshot of the test scenario.Please take a look.

Comment: What is the code of class "row"? Add things like  a System.out.println( trans.BUS_AREA_CD.length() ) to the second rule and see what happens. Read the documentation of the tool creating the "data object" row; maybe it adds code initializing strings to the null string.

Comment: I have tried System.out.println( trans.BUS_AREA_CD.length() ). When I pass BUS_AREA_CD = null then it is printing the length as 4, when I pass blank value it is printing zero.

Answer (score 0):

the problem of the Test Scenario you attached is that it assumes *null* as String value. If you want to crate instance of the *row* with the attribute *BUS_AREA_CD* equal to *null* then your *GIVEN* part should looks like this:

```
Insert 'row' [test]
```

Comment: @Srinu Katta I take it that this, without an entry for BUS_AREA_CD below, means that no field is set, neither with "null" (a string of length 4) nor "" (a string of length 0). Thus, the field will remain null (no String at all). The documentation for the tool should describe your options in detail.

Comment: @laune I will be implementing null as a string of length zero(BUS_AREA_CD.length() == 0). For blank validation, I am planning to use (BUS_AREA_CD == '')